# discord.py, Cogs: How Would I assign a nickname on join?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-bot

The title says the gist of what I'm asking.

I'm trying to make an `on_member_join` event that will assign a nickname to new users. It's not giving me any output other than the standard new user joining. It's in a cog.

Any and all help would be appreciated! I've scoured the internet and can't seem to find an answer for this.

Note: I've been coding off-and-on with python and d.py since 2020, self-taught. I'm decently advanced in it, so don't worry if the answer is complex.

I've tried the following code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
      await member.edit(nick="[G-P]" + member.name)
```

But it doesn't work. No erros are shown in the console either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out later. for some reason, the code just wasn't working. This actually did end up working as is!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the [Intents.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Intents.members) intent enabled in your code and on the developer portal, so it would look like:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

then add these intents to your bot constructor on your main file where you load your cogs.
Also go to the Developer Portal https://discord.com/developers/applications and on the bot section and enable `Server Members Intent`, also make sure your bot has the manage nicknames permission on your server.

Comment: I've done all of that already. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: hmm interesting perhaps you are using a old version of discord.py?

Comment: Nah, I use the latest.